# Strong law of large numbers with finite fourth moment

Tags: probability, convergence-divergence, law-of-large-numbers

My textbook (Introduction to probability, bertsekas 2nd ed pg 294) showed that $\frac{(X_1+\dots+X_n)^4}{n^4}$ converges to zero with probability 1 and then said that it implies $\frac{(X_1+\dots+X_n)}{n}$ converges to zero with probability 1. I am not sure how this follows.

Comment: $$Y\to0\iff\sqrt[4]{Y}\to0$$

Comment: Is that hard to prove. And we are dealing with a sequence of random variables here and not a sequence of numbers, so is there anything extra to be careful of.

Comment: But if $\{Y_n\}$ is a sequence of random variables then for each $\omega$ from the sample space the sequence $\{Y_n(\omega)\}$ is a sequence of numbers and you can check convergence at that point. What is being proved in your example is that the sequence $\frac{X_1+...+X_n}{n}$ converges to zero at almost every $\omega$. (i.e the set of such points $\omega$ has probability $1$)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $\overline{X}_n:=\frac1n\sum_{i=1}^nX_i$.

Then for every $\omega\in\Omega$ we have: $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\overline{X}_n(\omega)=0\iff\lim_{n\to\infty}\overline{X}_n^4(\omega)=0$$So expressed in sets: $$\left\{\lim_{n\to\infty}\overline{X}_n=0\right\}=\left\{\lim_{n\to\infty}\overline{X}_n^4=0\right\}$$ so that:$$P(\lim_{n\to\infty}\overline{X}_n=0)=P(\lim_{n\to\infty}\overline{X}_n^4=0)$$

Comment: Could you add a proof of the first equivalence.

Comment: Proving that is actually quite elementary. It can be done with e.g. $\epsilon$-$\delta$ method. Have you tried it yourself already?

Comment: I believe we have to choose $\delta$ so that $|y|<\epsilon^4$